# How should we write test for repository , logic and controller layer in laravel?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I am trying to write test for repository, logic and controller layer. Repository class injected inside logic and logic class injected to controller. I wrote the test for repository and mock repository in logic class to write test for logic. But for controller i wrote integration test like this:

```
public function test_create_role()
{
    $data = Role::factory()->make()->toArray();

    $this->postJson(route('roles.store'), $data)
        ->assertCreated();
}
```

Do I need to check if new data has been added to data base like this:

```
public function test_create_role()
{
    $data = Role::factory()->make()->toArray();

    $this->postJson(route('roles.store'), $data)
        ->assertCreated();

    $this->assertDatabaseHas('roles', $data);
}
```

Or is the repository test enough?
Do we need to test the repository layer and logic layer separately, or is integration testing enough?

Comment: As Laravel does not use Repositories but an Active Record (Eloquent), you should either assert that the database (or whatever source of truth is storing your data) that has the desired data after passing through the controller or you can just assert (using a [spy](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/spies.html)) that the expected Repository (and it's method) was correctly called

Answer (score 0):

Laravel uses active record, so there are no repositories, and you don't need to test it as it is part of the framework. Just assume that it just works. Focus more on app logic and data validity.